# Laravel no driver found for ibm db2 using laravel-db2

Tags: php, linux, laravel, db2, centos7

I have a Centos 7 machine with `php 7.3 apache` and a `laravel 5.8` application that need to connect to `db2 (as400)` database.
I have installed `ibm_db2` and `pdo_ibm` driver and extension through `ibm_data_server_driver_package_linuxx64_v11.5.tar.gz`.
The above drivers are installed as follow.
For ibm_db2 i used:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
yum install php-pear php-devel ksh
tar -zxf ibm_data_server_driver_package_linuxx64_v11.5.tar.gz 
mv dsdriver/ /opt/
cd /opt/dsdriver/
chmod +x installDSDriver 
ksh installDSDriver 
pecl install ibm_db2
```

for pdo_ibm since pecl requires PDO and the pecl PDO package is obsolete, i compiled  pdo_ibm from source:

```
pecl download PDO_IBM
tar -xzf PDO_IBM-1.3.6.tgz
cd PDO_IBM-1.3.6/
phpize
./configure --with-pdo-ibm=/opt/dsdriver/lib
make
make install
```

I have also installed I series client access through `iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.`
When i try to connect to database laravel returns

> PDOException could not find driver

I have installed `iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.`
using the following commands:

```
sudo yum install libiodbc
sudo yum install unixODBC.x86_64
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel.x86_64
cd /usr/lib64
sudo ln libodbcinst.so.2 libodbcinst.so.1
sudo ln libodbc.so.2 libodbc.so.1
sudo rpm -ivh iSeriesAccess-7.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm --nodeps
```

I have also installed `ibm_data_server_driver_package_linuxx64_v11.5` and  added `ibm_db2` extension.

My laravel db2 connection:

```php
'stealth' => [
            'driver'        => env('STEALTH_DB_DRIVER', 'db2_ibmi_ibm'), // or 'db2_ibmi_ibm' / 'db2_zos_odbc' / 'db2_expressc_odbc
            'driverName'    => env('STEALTH_DB_DRIVERNAME', '{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}'), // or '{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}' / '{IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit}'
            'host'          => env('STEALTH_DB_HOST', ''),
            'username'      => env('STEALTH_DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password'      => env('STEALTH_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'database'      => env('STEALTH_DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'prefix'        => env('STEALTH_DB_PREFIX', ''),
            'schema'        => env('STEALTH_DB_SCHEMA', ''),
            'port'          => env('STEALTH_DB_PORT', 50000),
            'date_format'   => env('STEALTH_DB_DATE_FORMAT', 'Y-m-d H:i:s'), // or 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' / 'Y-m-d-H.i.s.u'...
            'odbc_keywords' => [
                'SIGNON'                => env('STEALTH_DB_SIGNON', 3),
                'SSL'                   => env('STEALTH_DB_SSL', 0),
                'CommitMode'            => env('STEALTH_DB_COMMITMODE', 2),
                'ConnectionType'        => env('STEALTH_DB_CONNECTIONTYPE', 0),
                'DefaultLibraries'      => env('STEALTH_DB_DEFAULTLIBRARIES', ''),
                'Naming'                => env('STEALTH_DB_NAMING', 0),
                'UNICODESQL'            => env('STEALTH_DB_UNICODESQL', 0),
                'DateFormat'            => env('STEALTH_DB_DATEFORMAT', 5),
                'DateSeperator'         => env('STEALTH_DB_DATESEPERATOR', 0),
                'Decimal'               => env('STEALTH_DB_DECIMAL', 0),
                'TimeFormat'            => env('STEALTH_DB_TIMEFORMAT', 0),
                'TimeSeparator'         => env('STEALTH_DB_TIMESEPARATOR', 0),
                'TimestampFormat'       => env('STEALTH_DB_TIMESTAMPFORMAT', 0),
                'ConvertDateTimeToChar' => env('STEALTH_DB_CONVERTDATETIMETOCHAR', 0),
                'BLOCKFETCH'            => env('STEALTH_DB_BLOCKFETCH', 1),
                'BlockSizeKB'           => env('STEALTH_DB_BLOCKSIZEKB', 32),
                'AllowDataCompression'  => env('STEALTH_DB_ALLOWDATACOMPRESSION', 1),
                'CONCURRENCY'           => env('STEALTH_DB_CONCURRENCY', 0),
                'LAZYCLOSE'             => env('STEALTH_DB_LAZYCLOSE', 0),
                'MaxFieldLength'        => env('STEALTH_DB_MAXFIELDLENGTH', 15360),
                'PREFETCH'              => env('STEALTH_DB_PREFETCH', 0),
                'QUERYTIMEOUT'          => env('STEALTH_DB_QUERYTIMEOUT', 1),1,
                'DefaultPkgLibrary'     => env('STEALTH_DB_DEFAULTPKGLIBRARY', 'QGPL'),
                'DefaultPackage'        => env('STEALTH_DB_DEFAULTPACKAGE', 'A /DEFAULT(IBM),2,1,0'),
                'ExtendedDynamic'       => env('STEALTH_DB_EXTENDEDDYNAMIC', 0),
                'QAQQINILibrary'        => env('STEALTH_DB_QAQQINILIBRARY', ''),
                'SQDIAGCODE'            => env('STEALTH_DB_SQDIAGCODE', ''),
                'LANGUAGEID'            => env('STEALTH_DB_LANGUAGEID', 'ENU'),
                'SORTTABLE'             => env('STEALTH_DB_SORTTABLE', ''),
                'SortSequence'          => env('STEALTH_DB_SORTSEQUENCE', 0),
                'SORTWEIGHT'            => env('STEALTH_DB_SORTWEIGHT', 0),
                'AllowUnsupportedChar'  => env('STEALTH_DB_ALLOWUNSUPPORTEDCHAR', 0),
                'CCSID'                 => env('STEALTH_DB_CCSID', 819),819,
                'GRAPHIC'               => env('STEALTH_DB_GRAPHIC', 0),
                'ForceTranslation'      => env('STEALTH_DB_FORCETRANSLATION', 0),
                'ALLOWPROCCALLS'        => env('STEALTH_DB_ALLOWPROCCALLS', 0),
                'DB2SQLSTATES'          => env('STEALTH_DB_DB2SQLSTATES', 0),
                'DEBUG'                 => env('STEALTH_DB_DEBUG', 0),
                'TRUEAUTOCOMMIT'        => env('STEALTH_DB_TRUEAUTOCOMMIT', 0),
                'CATALOGOPTIONS'        => env('STEALTH_DB_CATALOGOPTIONS', 3),
                'LibraryView'           => env('STEALTH_DB_LIBRARYVIEW', 0),
                'ODBCRemarks'           => env('STEALTH_DB_ODBCREMARKS', 0),
                'SEARCHPATTERN'         => env('STEALTH_DB_SEARCHPATTERN', 1),
                'TranslationDLL'        => env('STEALTH_DB_TRANSLATIONDLL', ''),
                'TranslationOption'     => env('STEALTH_DB_TRANSLATIONOPTION', 0),
                'MAXTRACESIZE'          => env('STEALTH_DB_MAXTRACESIZE', 0),
                'MultipleTraceFiles'    => env('STEALTH_DB_MULTIPLETRACEFILES', 1),
                'TRACE'                 => env('STEALTH_DB_TRACE', 0),
                'TRACEFILENAME'         => env('STEALTH_DB_TRACEFILENAME', ''),
                'ExtendedColInfo'       => env('STEALTH_DB_EXTENDEDCOLINFO', 0),
            ],
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
                //PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING => false,
                //PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT => PDO::I5_TXN_NO_COMMIT,
                //PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT => false,
                //PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL => '',
                //PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB => '',
            ]
        ],
```

The `phpinfo` shows that the `ibm_db2`, `pdo_ibm` and `PDO` extensions are loaded but, when i try to connect to database laravel returns

> PDOException could not find driver

The error log shows me this

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ibm_db2.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/ibm_db2.so (libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/ibm_db2.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/ibm_db2.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_ibm.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_ibm.so (libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_ibm.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_ibm.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

the odbcinst.ini has the following content:

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description=iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver=/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup=/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1=If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2=the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64=/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64=/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading=2
DontDLClose=1
UsageCount=1

[iSeries Access ODBC Driver 64-bit]
Description=iSeries Access for Linux 64-bit ODBC Driver
Driver=/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup=/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading=2
DontDLClose=1
UsageCount=1
```

---

UPDATE 2019-08-29

I successfully installed ibm_db2 extension but pdo_ibm returns error during install.
I have executed the following commands:

```
#Install apache 2
yum -y install httpd
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http 
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload

#Install php 73
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY*
yum -y install epel-release
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum -y install yum-utils
yum update
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
yum -y install php php-opcache
systemctl restart httpd.service

yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ 
yum -y install php-cli 
yum -y install php-devel 
yum -y install php-pdo 
yum -y install php-mbstring 
yum -y install php-soap 
yum -y install php-gd 
yum -y install php-xml 
yum -y install php-pecl-apcu 
yum -y install unzip
yum -y install php-pear

export IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/dsdriver
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/dsdriver/lib

echo 'export IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/dsdriver' >> /etc/profile.d/db2env.sh
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/dsdriver/lib' >> /etc/profile.d/db2env.sh

systemctl start httpd.service

yum install ksh
mv v11.1.4fp4a_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz /opt/ibm/
cd /opt/ibm/
tar xf v11.1.4fp4a_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz 
rm v11.1.4fp4a_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz

mkdir /opt/ibm
mv v11.1.4fp4a_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz /opt/ibm/
cd /opt/ibm/
tar xf v11.1.4fp4a_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz 
rm v11.1.4fp4a_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz

cd dsdriver/
chmod 755 installDSDriver
ksh installDSDriver
pecl install ibm_db2
echo 'extension=ibm_db2.so' > /etc/php.d/pdo_db2.ini
service httpd restart


pecl download PDO_IBM 
tar -xzf PDO_IBM-1.3.6.tgz 
cd PDO_IBM-1.3.6/
phpize
./configure --with-pdo-ibm=/opt/dsdriver/lib
make
```

when i run make it returns:

```
/bin/sh /root/PDO_IBM-1.3.6/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/PDO_IBM-1.3.6/include -I/root/PDO_IBM-1.3.6/main -I/root/PDO_IBM-1.3.6 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -o pdo_ibm.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /root/PDO_IBM-1.3.6/modules  pdo_ibm.lo ibm_driver.lo ibm_statement.lo -Wl,-rpath, -L -ldb2
libtool: link: require no space between `-L' and `-ldb2'
make: *** [pdo_ibm.la] Error 1
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running PHP as PHP-FPM? If so, have you tried restarting it?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson no I'm not using fpm,

Comment: @mao for ibm_db2 i used pecl install ibm_db2 for pdo_ ibm i compiled it manually pecl download PDO_IBM
tar -xzf PDO_IBM-1.3.6.tgz 
cd PDO_IBM-1.3.6/
phpize
./configure --with-pdo-ibm=/opt/dsdriver/lib
make
make install

Comment: @mao i edited the question, i do not know how to perform sanity checks for pdo, and i do not understand what i have to put in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @mao I found the issue. pdo_ibm and ibm_db2 are not compatible with php 7.1 or higher. I tried with php 7.0 and php loads the extensions correctly.

Comment: @RiccardoFrancescato my centos 7.6 runs php 7.1.31 and connects successfully to Db2-LUW with pdo_ibm (built from v1.3.6).

Comment: @mao i'm trying to figure out how to perform the installation. At the moment i successfully installed ibm_db2 but no pdo_ibm, i'm trying to compile it from source but make returns: "libtool: link: require no space between `-L' and `-ldb2'
make: *** [pdo_ibm.la] Error 1". How you installed ibm_db2 and pdo_ibm on your machine? Do you have a script or a guide? Thanks for the patient.

Comment: @RiccardoFrancescato I followed the Db2-Knowledge-centre documented steps to build v1.3.6 of pdo_ibm, as a non-privileged user, phpize, ./configure, make, make test, sudo make install. One detail is that I have a local Db2-server and IBM_DB_HOME environment variable points to /home/db2inst1/sqllib for all sessions that use the databases and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correctly set.